# Proving that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} f(a+h) $

Tags: real-analysis, limits

The Question:

Verify that if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists, then $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}f(a+h)$.

My plan is to use the theorem showing that the limit of a sum is the sum of the limits.  By that theorem, $\lim_{h\to 0}f(a+h)=\lim_{h\to 0}f(a)+\lim_{h\to 0}f(h)=f(a)+0=f(a)=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$.

Does this proof hold?  Please let me know if there is anything that I need to clarify.

Comment: Can you state clearly your theorem? It seems to me that the theorem cannot be applied in your case.

Comment: Generally, if lim(x->a)f(x) exists, then lim(x->a)f(x+h) = lim(x->a)f(x)+lim(x->a)f(h).  Is this incorrect?

Comment: you can't write $\lim_{h \to 0}f(a + h) = \lim_{h \to 0}f(a) + \lim_{h \to 0}f(h)$

Comment: I think the theorem you mentioned is $\lim_{x\to a} (g(x) + f(x)) = \lim_{x\to a} g(x) + \lim_{x\to a}f(x)$. It involves two functions $f$ and $g$. In your case you have only one function.

Comment: Okay I see now.  So which direction should I move in to prove this?

Answer (score 3):

The limit $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists and is equal to $b$: $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=b$$ if and only if for each $\varepsilon\in\mathbb R^+$ exists $\delta\in\mathbb R^+$ such that $$\forall x,0<|x-a|<\delta\implies|f(x)-b|<\varepsilon.$$

**Hint:**
Apply analogous definition for $\lim_{h\to0}f(a+h)$ and tell if you can derive one from the other.

Comment: "such *that*" (FYI)

Answer (score -1):

Well first we have to prove that differentiability implies continuity. (We have to prove that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists.)

Thus, suppose we have a differentiable function $f(x)$ such that $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$. This equals $f'(a)$.

Now, we multiply each side by $h$. Thus, we get $\lim_{h\to 0}hf'(a)$. (What is the answer here?)

Thus, we get $\lim_{h\to 0}f(a+h) \to f(a)$. **(Why?)**

Thus, we set $x = a + h$. Thus, $\lim_{x-a \to 0}f(x) \to f(a)$.

Thus, we have proven that such a $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = f(a)$ exists.

The answer to your question:

> To answer your question, go backwards!

Comment: "Well first we have to prove that differentiability implies continuity." **Why?**

Comment: "Verify that $lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists"

Comment: What does that have to do with differentiability? We're talking continuity here.

Comment: I agree with Pedro Tamaroff, this is a simple question on limits, why do we need to invoke differentiation?

Comment: It was just another way of rephrasing the question! Hence the parentheses. Isn't it still correct?

Comment: The question really has nothing to do with differentiability.