# ε-δ: Proving that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} f(a+h) $

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Firstly, I do realize that this proof was asked about before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534070/proving-that-lim-x-rightarrow-afx-lim-h-rightarrow-0-fah), but the proposed proof was different and the answers were also not complete.

To get to the point: I have written my own proof of this simple theorem, however I'm not sure if the proof is correct--the exercise is taken from Spivak, who seems to have provided different and more elaborate proof of that theorem.

My proof is following:

By the definition of limit (omitting the 'for all's and 'there exists''):

$$ \lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L_1 \implies 0 < |x - a| < δ_1 \implies |f(x) - L_1| < ε $$
and
$$ \lim_{h\to 0} f(a + h) = L_2 \implies 0 < |h - 0| = |h| < δ_2 \implies |f(a + h) - L_2| < ε $$

Let's work on the second limit:
$$|h| = |(a+h) - a|$$
$$\text{Let } y = a + h$$
Now, the second limit takes the following definition:
$$ 0 < |y - a| < δ_2 \implies |f(y) - L_2| < ε $$
We see that both limits have the exact same form right now. By Theorem 1 [stating that if limit L exists it is necessarily unique] $L_1 = L_2$ and $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} f(a + h)$ $$Q.E.D.$$

Is my reasoning correct or have I made an error somewhere?

Comment: Is there a link to the proof provided by Spivak?

Answer (score 2):

Correct and exact reasoning. Also remember that it's important to respect the formalism and write all the necessary quantifiers.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the necessity of the formalism, but decided to omit the quantifiers in the post for the sake of brevity.